# Probability of a family having 2 boys and 1 girl

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm working with the following problem:

> Your new neighbors have three children. You are told that they have three children, but without knowing their gender. If you are told about three independent observations of a boy (meaning not knowing whether it's the same boy or different boys), what is the probability that they have two boys and a girl?

Let's form our sample space $S = \{bbb, bbg,....,ggb,ggg\}$

Now we let $H_i = \{$observing $i$ boys$\}$

From this, it becomes evident that $P(H_0) = P(H_3) = 1/8$ whereas $P(H_1) = P(H_2) = 3/8$

We also let $E$ be the event of the family having 2 boys and 1 girl.

From this, we can calculate:

$$P(E|H_0) = P(E|H_3) = 0$$
and
$$P(E|H_1) = 3 (1/3)^2 (2/3) = 2/9$$
and lastly
$$P(E|H_2) = 3 (2/3)^2 (1/3) = 4/9$$

Now, using Bayes theorem, we get that:

$$P(H_2 | E) = \frac{P(H_2)P(E|A_2)}{P(E)}$$

but $P(E) = P(E|H_1)P(H_1) + P(E|H_2)P(H_2)$ from law of total probability, hence:

$$P(A_2 | E) = \frac{P(H_2)P(E|H_2)}{P(E|H_1)P(H_1) + P(E|H_2)P(H_2)} = $$

$$ = \frac{1}{1+\frac{P(E|H_1)P(H_1)}{P(E|H_2)P(H_2)}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{2/9}{4/9}} = 2/3$$

but according to my answer sheet, this is not the correct answer. I also can't see where it goes wrong in my solution and would be glad if anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be making an implicit assumption that all children are either boys or girls?

Comment: Kindly post a screenshot of the answer from the answer sheet. If I get the same answer, I shall share it.. Thanks

Comment: @Dr. Sundar its 4/9

Comment: @joriki I'm sorry but I don't really see where I made that assumption. If you are thinking about the part where I calculated the $P(E|H_i)$'s, I thought I had an urn with $i$ boys in it and $3-i$ girls, then that's how I calculated the probabilities. Or maybe there's something else you're thinking about.

Comment: I don't understand. The problem says that the neighbours have $3$ children. You assume that these are $i$ boys and $3-i$ girls. Isn't that equivalent to assuming that all the children are either boys or girls?

Comment: This is not clear. What constitutes an independent observation of a boy? Are you saying that someone uniformly at random selects a child and observes it to be a boy? Something else?

Comment: @lulu I've rephrased the question. Sorry.

Comment: Still not clear. Problems like these tend to come down to details and assumptions. Here, it seems you meant to assume that each child was either a boy or a girl with probability $\frac 12$ of each and that each event was independent of the other gender selections. And I imagine that I got the "independent observation" thing right but it isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguously worded and assumptions are not clearly stated. If we assume that $(i)$ there are three observations and each observation is an independent event, $(ii)$ in each observation, it is equally likely to see any of the three children, and $(iii)$ each child is equally likely to be a boy or a girl,

Say, the event of observing a boy in all three observations is $A$.

$ \displaystyle \small P(B = 2, G = 1 \mid A) = \frac{P(A \mid B = 2, G = 1) \cdot P(B=2, G =1)}{P(A)}$

$ \small P(A) = P(A \mid B = 3) \cdot P(B=3) + P(A \mid B = 2, G = 1) \cdot P(B=2, G =1) + P(A \mid B = 1, G = 2) \cdot P(B=1, G =3)$

$ \displaystyle \small  = \frac 18 + \frac 23 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac {3}{8} + \frac 13 \cdot \frac 13 \cdot \frac 13 \cdot \frac {3}{8} = \frac 14$

$ \displaystyle \small P(A \mid B = 2, G = 1) \cdot P(B=2, G =1) = \frac 23 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac {3}{8} = \frac 19$

That leads to,

$ \displaystyle \small P(B = 2, G = 1 \mid A) = \frac 49$

Answer (score 1):

You are not understanding the problem correctly. The probability of observing 3 boys is bigger than $ \frac{1}{8} $. It is bigger than this, since $ \frac{1}{8} $ is the probability that the family does indeed have three boys. If this is the case you are certain to observe three boys. However you can observe three boys even if the family has 1 boy and 2 girls (try to calculate it).
You need to separate (in your head) the probabilities of how many boys the family has and the probabilities of how many boys you are observing.
For starting try to calculate the following:
$ A_i = $ {the family has $i$ boys}
$ H_i = $ {you are observing $i$ boys}
Now what is $ P(H_3|A_i) $, for $ i = 0,1,2,3 $?

Hint: obviously $ P(H_3|A_0) = 0 $ and $ P(H_3|A_3) = 1 $

Comment: If I change $H_i$ to the event that the $i$:th observation is a boy. Does this make the right move?

Comment: @Tanamas edited answer to make it clearer